# Best practice for updating a list returned from Parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am currently creating a new adapter with the list of objects returned by Parse and then doing a `.setAdapter()`. This unsettles me because it seems like I'm recreating the adapter unnecessarily as opposed to modifying the existing list reference then just calling `.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

The only other thing I can think of is comparing the old list with the new and adding/deleting objects to update the state of the old list based on the objects that I'm returned by Parse. Is the best practice way to do this?

I'm also hesitant to just add the item to my list because I don't want to go down this path of possibly having inconsistent data between the Parse server and my client.

I guess what I'm ultimately looking for is whether there is a callback Parse provides if the list of objects gets updated.

[[screenshot here] I just have this visceral feeling that I'm committing an Android crime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVDv5.png)

Comment: For the legacy Listview, changing the list's data and calling notify... is enough.

Comment: You can do this be using a getter/setter in your adapter that will set the adapters data to be the new list, and calling notifyDatasetChanged(). This is something you just have to do because, as you have identified, the list data could be all different and you want the data consistent on the client side. This method will be a little more efficient since you are updating an existing adapter, instead of creating a whole new one.

Comment: To get nice add/remove/change animations in a recyclerview there is no other way to compare the items.If you don't whant it, call just datasetchanged(). Such a callback dosen't exist , cause that's not the way parse works. Take a look at e.g. Firebase which provides such callbacks.

Comment: I guess he is using ListView instead. If you use RecyclerView, please show more code so we can help. Comparing items can be done by SortedList though.

Comment: If I set the list that was used in the constructor of the ArrayAdapter and then call .notifyDataSetChanged(), this was not enough to cause the ListView to update. I assumed this was because the array adapter was still holding a reference to the old list even though it's still the same member variable.

Comment: (and yes I am using ListView as opposed to the RecyclerView)